# Getting EADDRINUSE error in node.js when specifying hostname

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, localhost

I am getting an EADDRINUSE error on nodejs when trying to run this code:

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require('http')    
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = 3000

const app = express()

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.headers)
    res.statusCode = 200
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.end('<html><body><h1>This is response</h1></body></html>')
})

server.listen(hostname,port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http:${hostname}//:${port}`)
})

const server = http.createServer(app)

server.listen(hostname,port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http:{}//:${port}`)
})
```

I tried changing the ports but it still gave the same error.
The peculiar this is that if I remove the hostname - "localhost" and only listen to the port the code works.

Please explain what could be the issue?

Here is the stack trace :

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE localhost
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1350:19)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1503:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/shikhar/D/Study/git-test/node-express/index.js:30:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: try using just `app.listen(port, callback)`

Comment: No behind proxy.
app.listen gives the same error when I pass hostname